# the meaninings of two ** for an iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

In the following code segment

```
vector<SceneObject *> sceneObjs;
vector<SceneObject *>::iterator iter;

iter = sceneObjs.begin();
while (iter != sceneObjs.end()){
  cout << **iter <<endl;
  iter++;
}
```

why **iter has two *s ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first * dereferences the iterator, giving a `SceneObject *` pointer. The second * dereferences this `SceneObject *` pointer to the `SceneObject` itself.

Answer (score 11):

Because `*iter` is a `SceneObject *&` - **a `SceneObject` pointer**. You need to dereference it to get to the real `SceneObject`.

Comment: Ssh, don't tell anyone, but `*iter` is actually a `SceneObject*&`, but it doesn't change the rest here.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I really don't know enough C++ for this but I'll incorporate this into the answer, thanks!

Comment: @cnicutar In this case the reference part does not make any difference. The reference makes it possible for the code using the iterator to change the content of the iterator (the pointer of the iterator, not the memory where the pointer inside the iterator pints to). The reference is also important when you make a call to a function, which itself takes a `SceneObject*&` reference, since this function can then replace the content of *it to another value. When you have a function `void setNull(SceneObject*& obj){obj=NULL;}`, than a call `setNull(*iter);` set the content of the iterator to NULL.

Answer (score 5):

Because `*iter` returns a `SceneObject*` which will then be again dereferenced by the second `*`.

Answer (score 3):

The first `*` returns the vale in the iterator, a `SceneObject*` pointer. The second `*` deferences that pointer, giving a `SceneObject`. I suspect there's an overload for `<<` that renders the SceneObject` to a stream.